# My messagebox alert keeps on occuring even though I've entered the correct input the second time around

Tags: vb.net

I have a code where I will enter a payment and it will show a messagebox if I've entered a `payment` which is less than the `total` amount. I intentionally entered a `payment` which is less than the `total` amount for testing purposes however during the second time which I remove the number in the textbox and enter the right amount, the messagebox is still showing

```
  If (paymentbox.Text < total) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter sufficient amount of payment")


    Else
      
        changebox.Text = paymentbox.Text - total

        totalpricebox.Text = total.ToString("c")

    End If
```

btw this code is in my ordernbtn_click event, Im looking to refresh a form since I can't do `Me.Close()` and `Me.Show()` at the same time but any suggestion will help.

Comment: Is `total`  an integer?

Comment: Set `Option Strict On` and you will find the problem right after.

Comment: yes `total` is an integer @ZeroWorks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just parse `Paymentbox.Text` before check and should work:

```
    Dim payment As Integer

    If (Integer.TryParse(paymentbox.Text, payment)) Then
        If (payment < total) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter sufficient amount of payment")
        Else
            'Do stuff
        End If

    Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid amount of payment")
    End If
```

`Integer.TrayParse` will check if the input text is valid and return `true` if it's and will change payment variable with a valid `integer`.

Comment: Got it! looks like my `total` keeps on adding up because my `checkbox` remains checked every time I hit the `orderbtn` event and also I've set my `total` to `0` to solve the problem :)